# Indexing File Share get properties of files

Tags: search-results, crawling, file-server

I've successfully configured a content source to index a file share with SharePoint. So on this share are Office files, pictures, ... stored. These files contain several properties like on the screenshot.  [image]

Is there any solution to get these properties in my search results?
Regards Michael

Answer (score 1):

Not that I have seen from the out of the box Image File Handler. You can replace the Image handler with a better IFilter, like the one from IFilterShop.com and then recrawl the files. This will create the crawled properties for the EXIF and XMP data in the files. Then you can create the managed properties for use in Search. I have a couple OLD articles on how to do this if you need additional steps. http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2008/08/30/sharepoint-image-search-part-2/